# For idempotent matrices $A, B$ prove $I - (A+B)$ being invertible implies $rkA = rkB$

Tags: linear-algebra

I've gathered some facts and tried to glue them into some sort of solution but nothing really comes to my mind. I believe, as matrices are idempotent, I should show that $trA = trB$ somehow. I tried to think about solution involving eigenvalues (as trace is their sum) but I couldn't go come up with anything.

Could you provide some hints please?

Comment: what does $E$ stand for?

Comment: @Alexdanut, it should be $I$. In Russian books identity matrix is usually denoted by $E$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will use the well-known result that multiplication by an invertible matrix doesn't affect the rank.
We have that $A(I-A-B)=A-A^2-AB=-AB$ and by using the result above it follows that $\operatorname{rank}A=\operatorname{rank}(AB)$.
Furthermore, $(I_n-A-B)B=-AB$, so $\operatorname{rank}B=\operatorname{rank}(AB)$.
Hence, $\operatorname{rank}A=\operatorname{rank}B=\operatorname{rank}(AB)$.

Comment: how $$A-A^{2}-AB=-AB?$$

Comment: @Naman $A$ is idempotent which means that $A=A^2$

Comment: oh yeah. I mistook idempotent with nilpotent. my mistake